# Regular octahedron - matrices orthogonales $3 \times 3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just started a course of Abstract Algebra, and the teacher asked the following question :

List the orthogonal matrices that transform regular octahedron itself.

Here's what I found so far.

I = $ \begin{array}{lc} \left(\begin{matrix}
                    1 & 0 & 0 \\
                    0 & 1 & 0 \\
                    0 & 0 & 1
      \end{matrix}\right) \\\end{array}$ - Identity matrix

$M_k$ = $ \begin{array}{lc} \left(\begin{matrix}
                    \cos2\pi k / 4 & -\sin2\pi k / 4 & 0 \\
                    \sin2\pi k / 4& \cos2\pi k / 4& 0 \\
                    0 & 0 & 1
      \end{matrix}\right) \\\end{array}$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ - rotation where the rotation axis is the z-axis.

$N_k$ = $ \begin{array}{lc} \left(\begin{matrix}
                    \cos2\pi k / 4 & \sin2\pi k / 4 & 0 \\
                    \sin2\pi k / 4& -\cos2\pi k / 4& 0 \\
                    0 & 0 & 1
      \end{matrix}\right) \\\end{array}$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ - reflection

I think there must be 24 elements - matrices.

Note: the vertices of the octahedron are chosen to  6 points $(± 1,0,0)$, $(0, ± 1,0)$, $(0,0, ± 1) $

Does someone could correct and complete what I have done so far? I can't finish what I started.

Comment: Is it true that you are looking for every rotation matrix that rotates the octahedron and still shows the same shape, because of its symmetry? If that's the case I might be able to help you. Sorry English is not my native language.

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OctahedralGroup.html.